# How import and use an external library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to use libxl library in visual studio, I know I have to add some terms in properties section of each project to use new library but the folder of this library (that I download it perviously) contains many sub-folders, So i don't know where should copy each sub-folder.

The subfolders of the library's folder
[image]

The two sub-folders -include_c and include_cpp- contains header files.

The download link of this library is http://www.libxl.com/download.html.

Please tell me how import library to visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple tutorial to do it in visual studio, in the same web site for that library

http://libxl.com/vscpp.html

Follow each step to be able to import this library.

Comment: Thx a lot I had searched  it but i couldn't find it, you are perfect in searching:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through this section http://www.libxl.com/setup.html

It clearly says what to do with visual studio here http://www.libxl.com/vscpp.html