# Adding an external library built from source to c++ visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-linking

I'm trying to include an external library to my visual studio project on windows.
The library in question is mpg123, to decode mp3 files.

I followed the install instructions included with the library download, which said to do:

```
    ./configure
    make
    make install
```

and tried different configurations. Loading the header files works, and makes intellisense detect the methods I'm trying to use in my project, but I think I also need to include a .lib file, that would have to be included in the build. None of the configurations for Make have resulted in any .lib files.

I'm not familiar yet with third party files for c++ projects and linking, and the internet is not helpful in telling me what exactly I need to do make this work.

Comment: Some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file

Comment: Yeah, because visual studio in principle is also not very helpful with setting up anything ... Some instructions on how to "click" your things together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670931/4165552, [approach with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74742934/4165552), and some [link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33405884/4165552) but seems to point to the correct tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use vcpkg to config the mpg123 in Visual Studio.

[image]
E.g.

CMD :  `vcpkg install mpg123:x64-windows` and **vcpkg** will download the mpg library, then add DLL reference for project automatically.

For  adding mpg123 manually, please read the tutorial: [Create a client app that uses the DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#create-a-client-app-that-uses-the-dll)